# Create and use Database in phoneGap is not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to the PhoneGap(2.9.0) and I was trying to create a database and ran the Android emulator but it was not going fine instead it is giving some error like "Unfortunately the app has been stopped", I do not know what went wrong with my below code.

Please do not consider my question as a duplicate, because I have seen many questions in stock over flow and tried to solve the problem but I did not get any solution.

I think the 'deviceready' event is not working properly even though I include cordova.js file.

The below is my code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        // this will be empty since no rows were inserted.
        console.log("Insert ID = " + results.insertId);
        // this will be 0 since it is a select statement
        console.log("Rows Affected = " + results.rowAffected);
        // the number of rows returned by the select statement
        console.log("Insert ID = " + results.rows.length);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to insert an alert statement and check whether the onDeviceReady() is getting fired. `function onDeviceReady() { alert("onDeviceReady fired!");}`. If see an alert on your device it means it is working.

Comment: `giving some error like "Unfortunately the app has been stopped"` -- What is the EXACT error you are getting? When does this happen in the process? Where are you seeing the error (console, alert, ?)? What is your SDK? The code you have pasted is straight from PhoneGap docs, so it looks ok.

Comment: Post the logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the output for my query with small corrections.

1) I have given the proper for cordova.js file
2) Remove the opening data base from the 'successCB' function and made it global.

The following code has been successfully executed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

      var db;
    // Populate the database
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        alert('Table DEMO will be created');
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Query the database
    //
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var htmlString = '';
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("No of rows in the table " + len);
        // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
        if (!results.rowsAffected) {
            console.log('No rows affected!');
            return false;
        }

        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        htmlString += '<li>' + results.rows.item(i).id + '<br/>' + results.rows.item(i).data + '</li>';
        }
        $('#listview').html(htmlString);
        // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
        console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(err) {
        console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert('successed');
        db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("Database has been started");
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        alert(db);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
    <ul id="listview"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```